# How to fill the values of previous cells based on the value of the other cell?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the following,

```
    a     |  count 
2020-03-29|  
2020-03-30|
2020-03-31|
2020-04-01|
2020-04-02|
2020-04-03|
2020-04-04|    1
2020-04-05|  
2020-04-06|
2020-04-07|
2020-04-08|
2020-04-09|
2020-04-10|
2020-04-11|    2
..
..
.. and so on
```

The structure of the df is like this, that is, there is a number after every 6 cells or days. How can I replace the blank values with the number at every 7th (or 7th multiple) cell backwards?

Final df should look like the following,

```
    a     |  count 
2020-03-29|    1 
2020-03-30|    1
2020-03-31|    1
2020-04-01|    1
2020-04-02|    1
2020-04-03|    1
2020-04-04|    1
2020-04-05|    2  
2020-04-06|    2
2020-04-07|    2
2020-04-08|    2
2020-04-09|    2
2020-04-10|    2
2020-04-11|    2
..
..
.. and so on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
df['count'] = df['count'].bfill()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `method` argument of [`pandas.DataFrame.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

- `backfill / bfill`: use next valid observation to fill gap

```py
df['count'] = df['count'].fillna(method='bfill')
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to backfill. See here for additional information on filling missing data: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

in your case, you would do:

```
df['count'].bfill()
```

or,

```
df['count'].fillna(method='bfill')
```